# Why does my javascript not reposition this heading?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to position a block of page headers to the right of an HTML page display, with the actual position depending on the width of the available window.  There's a div containing an image and a div containing a line of text "buttons" below it.

Both divs have `position: absolute` set and I want to set `top` and `left` using a javascript function when the page has loaded.  I'm obviously missing something, because the javascript has no effect on the display - the position is always as taken from the style sheet (default zeroes or actual values: I've tried both).

This is the code, cut down to try to isolate the problem.  The alert at the bottom seems to show that the left value is as I expect (890px in my test case), but the actual position (and the value reported by Firebug) is 630px.  I've tried it on Firefox 4.0.1 and Chrome 11 with the same effect.

```
<body onload="javascript:positionHeaders()">
  <div id="pageheader">  
    <div id="pageheader1a">  
      x  
    </div>  
    <div id="pageheader1b">  
      x  
    </div>  
    <div id="pageheader2a">  
      <img src="../images/memooirs2_320x58.png" class="nonhreflink"   
       onclick="prepareIndexDisplay()" />  
    </div>  
    <div id="pageheader2b">  
      <span class="smallbutton" onclick="processLogout()">Logout</span><span class="smallbutton" onclick="prepareHelp()">Help</span><span class="smallbutton" onclick="prepareTour()">Take a tour</span>  
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>  

#pageheader {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0px;  
  left: 0px;  
  width: 100%;  
  height: 80px;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);  
  background-image: url("../images/headerbkg.png");  
  background-repeat: repeat-x;  
  background-position: top;  
}  
#pageheader1a {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;  
}  
#pageheader1b {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 63px;  
  left: 0;  
}  
#pageheader2a {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;  
  left: 630px;  
}  
#pageheader2b {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 63px;  
  left: 630px;  
}  
.smallbutton {  
  position: relative;  
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;  
  border: 0;  
  padding: 0;  
  font-size: 0.8em;  
  font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  
  color: rgb(50,50,50);  
}  

function positionHeaders() {  
  var lWidth = 0, lHeight = 0;  
  if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {  //Non-IE  
    lWidth = window.innerWidth;  
    lHeight = window.innerHeight;  
  }  
  else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth ||     
   document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {  //IE 6+ standards compliant mode  
    lWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;  
    lHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;  
  }  
  else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth ||  
   document.body.clientHeight)) {  //IE 4 compatible  
    lWidth = document.body.clientWidth;  
    lHeight = document.body.clientHeight;  
  }  

  var z1 = String(lWidth - 550);  
  document.getElementById("pageheader2a").top = "0";   
  document.getElementById("pageheader2a").left = z1 + "px";  
  document.getElementById("pageheader2b").top = "63px";  
  document.getElementById("pageheader2b").left = z1 + "px";  
  alert("2bleft=" + document.getElementById("pageheader2b").left);       
}
```

Comment: This probably can be done with only html and css. If JS is necessary, I would then recommend jQuery since the code would be much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the properties you're setting at the end of `positionHeaders()` are correct? I would probably set their styles instead; something like:

```
document.getElementById("pageheader2a").style.top = "0";
```

Hope that helps.